# Do I Have To Recreate Custom List Forms If I Recreate The List?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, customization

I had made a list and created a custom list form (Insert -> Sharepoint Controls -> Custom List Form).  Then, I completely deleted the list (but copied the custom list form) and then recreated it, having changed a few fields.  There is only one field I'm concerned with on my custom list form and it hasn't changed in name or datatype and the list name hasn't changed either.  Do I need to regenerate (and then customize) the Custom List Form or can I just use the copy I made and cut/paste it back into the list folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one answered and I have a solution that works well enough.  I just don't know if it's optimal:

1. Copy the old/current list GUID.
2. Delete and recreate the list.
3. Copy the new list GUID.
4. For each custom list form, find and replace the old list GUID with the new list GUID.
5. Remove/Update any references to the data parameters near the beginning of the list form web part.
6. Remove/Update any references to the parameters in the actual fields.